# how java program enforce library version?

Tags: java, jar, version

For example,

If I have a program a.jar depend on log4j-1.0.jar, I make it and it works fine on my machine.

Later on, I copy my program to another machine, which has log4j-2.0.jar, which is not compatible with my program.

How will java runtime discover that? By an exception in the code? That sounds too scary...

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such scenario once. Yes if you provide two different  log4j library versions in the Class path Java runtime will discover both of them and there is no guarantee which will be picked up and may led to Exception/Error **specially if library is not backward compatible**.

**Most Java classloaders don't give any guarantees about the order in which libraries will be loaded, so you really need to be sure not to duplicate dependencies on your classpath.**

Comment: How does it answer the question, which is how to tackle this situation.

Comment: You should not have two versions of same library in the class path.If you do you cannot guarantee the behavior. So only way out is to find and remove multiple versions of jars.

Comment: You don't understand the problem here. There are not two version of jar in the classpath. The problem the version of jar in the classpath is different from the version of jar used to compiled the class.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Point remains the same!! Now if the version in the other computer is higher that the one project was compiled with code should run as long as the library is backward compatible(which in most of the case is). If the version is less than the compiled one and you are using any function not same as the 1 in older lib ull run into problem. This case generally does not arise because when we create and ship a product we also ship all the required libraries(dependencies) with it(and even if not it will be specified in the requirements section).

Comment: @JunedAhsan It is like saying I compiled the code on java 7 and what should I do if it encounters problem running on java 6.You have to install java7 or ask for the same product compatible for java 6 from the corresponding vendor.

Answer (score 0):

This question makes sense in the context of a web container. If we are talking about a desktop or JNLP application then the answer is simple: All library jar dependencies should be packaged with your application. We can never rely on some library file being on the class path of the client machine unless we explicitly placed it there, in which case we would know what version of the library is found.

In the case of a web application, the situation is exactly as scary as the question suggests. For instance, we might place a number of library files in the /lib directory of Tomcat, then deploy some war file that depends on a different version of one of these. The only indication of the failing dependency will be some (possibly non-obvious) exception. I was pulling my hair out over differences in Jersey versions for RESTful web services.

The solution is again to package everything into your application. This may make the war file very large, but re-deployments can be done by just updating the relevant files and then restarting the container. Some cloud services providers force us to do this because the developer is not given access to the shared /lib directory.